# Border conditions on the separation surface (Electromagnetism & Optics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

My teacher taught me that we can consider the following equation:

$$E_{1t}=E_{2t}$$

to  the descontinuity of the electric field tangent component on the separation surface of two means with different refraction indexes.

He didn't explain how to get there. But I think that it came from the Maxwell's law:

$$[\nabla\times \vec{E}]=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}  $$

If we consider a closed rectangular path that penetrates perpendicularly the separation surface we have:

$$\oint_{\gamma}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}=\int_{\gamma_{t1}}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}+\int_{\gamma_{t2}}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}+\int_{\gamma_{n1}}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}+\int_{\gamma_{n2}}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}$$

where "$n$" and "$t$" are notations for the normal and tangential components respectively.

If the height of the path goes to $0$. Then we have:

$$\oint_{\gamma}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}=\int_{\gamma_{t1}}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}+\int_{\gamma_{t2}}\vec{E}.\vec{dl}=E_{t1}l-E_{t2}l$$

Applying Stokes theorem:

$$\iint_{S}[\nabla\times\vec{E}].\vec{n}\text{ }{dS}=E_{t1}l-E_{t2}l$$

So, we can see that $E_{1t}=E_{2t}$ only if $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}=0$. For a electromagnetic wave we have:

$$[\vec{k}\times \vec{E}]=\mu \omega\vec{H}\Leftrightarrow \vec{B}=\frac{1}{v}[\vec{n} \times \vec{E}]$$

Could I say on the separation surface $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial \vec{B}/\partial t \neq 0$ on the surface, but you don't need it to be zero.  By your logic, you have
$$
(E_{1t} - E_{2t}) l = \iint_S [\nabla \times \vec{E}] . \vec{n}\,  d S   = - \iint_S \left[ \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \right] . \vec{n}\,  d S = - \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \iint_S \vec{B} . \vec{n}\,  d S \right] = - \frac{d\Phi}{dt}.
$$
This means that you just need $d \Phi/d t = 0$ over the surface bounded by your loop.  And since you're taking the limit as the height of the loop goes to zero, the flux through the loop is identically zero.  QED.

Comment: I've clarified the logic in my answer a bit;  does that address your question?

Comment: Oh.. I didn't remember that. You're right!

Comment: But it wasn't supposed to be a partial derivative and not a total derivative from Leibniz rule?

Comment: They're equivalent if the loop is fixed in space, I'm pretty sure.