# Interface conditions for $\vec E (\vec r,t)$ and $\vec B (\vec r,t)$

Tags: electromagnetism

When I tried to find the interface conditions in electrostatic, for the electric field $\vec E (\vec r)$ I used the 2nd Maxwell equation in electrostatic : $\nabla \times \vec E(\vec r)=0$.
Considering a small region between the two interfaces (each with a different $\epsilon$ value), I did:

$$\int_{(F)}\vec E(\vec r) d\vec r=0 \longrightarrow E_t^{(2)}(\vec r) - E_t^{(1)}(\vec r)=0 $$

$E_t^{(2)}(\vec r)$ is the tangential component of the $\vec E$ field in the second region.

$E_t^{(1)}(\vec r)$ is the tangential component of the $\vec E$ field in the first region.

$\int_{(F)} d\vec r$ is the line integral over some arbitrary region.

From the equation it is implied that the tangential components of the electric fields are equal.

I am trying to do the same thing for the case where $\vec E (\vec r,t)$. The Maxwell equation in this case is: $\nabla \times \vec E(\vec r,t) + \frac {\partial \vec B (\vec r,t)}{\partial t}$.
Then we have:

$$\int_{(F)}\vec E(\vec r,t) d\vec r=- \frac {d}{dt} \int_F\vec B (\vec r,t)d\vec f$$

And in my script it is said that:

$$E_t^{(1)}(\vec r,t)=E_t^{(2)}(\vec r,t)$$.

How did we got this expression? What happened with right side integral. We have the derivation of the magnetic induction not zero like we had in electrostatic. Can anyone explain this part to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Border conditions on the separation surface (Electromagnetism & Optics)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191143/border-conditions-on-the-separation-surface-electromagnetism-optics) or perhaps better ;)  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529950/electric-field-boundary-conditions-in-the-radiation-regime

Comment: yes this does answer my question. but I don't understand why does the partial time derivative changes to total derivative? An answer in one of the links is: "They're equivalent if the loop is fixed in space". What does being in space or not has to do with whether we use partial or full time derivative?

Comment: Because if DA IS a function of time, Then changing the derivative to a total derivative would change the answer in the following: Given Da is a function of (x(t),y(t),z(t)) aka the loop I  choose is moving with time If i were to take the total derivative of this, then the total answer would change depending on the loops speed, But the contrary, If i use the partial derivate, Then DA is independant of partial T, as it doesnt explicitly depend on T

Comment: This can also be easily seen, as if the partial derivative is inside the function, Then if db/dt is zero, then the emf MUST be zero, But consider i take the TOTAL time derivative outside the integral. if B is NOT a function of T, but DA IS! then there would be a non zero emf due to the electric field, which is nonsense because  we have shown before that if db/dt is zero then the integral must be zero

Comment: And if Da is a function of time, the total derivative would be a product rule between B and DA, which isnt present in the actual form

Comment: what exactly is Da?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that in the limit as your path gets closer and closer to the boundary, the  area gets smaller and smaller, meaning the flux enclosed approaches zero meaning the right side is also zero